# using pandas Generate csv file using if condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have columns like `start_time`, `end_time` and `time_taken` in minutes.
I want to generate a csv file with full data **only if `time_taken` equals to 10 minutes**.

My current code is:

```
if ( df['time_taken']) == 10:
  df.to_csv(r'result.csv')
```

It is giving error like:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the dataframe before saving, thus only saving the part of the dataframe that matches your condition:

```
df.loc[df.time_taken == 10].to_csv("results.csv")
```

You might want to read up on [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: No need to use `.loc` in this case : `df[df.time_taken == 10].to_csv("results.csv")`